# Downloading the file on daily basis

Tags: c#, javascript, download, extract

I've very strange issue while downloading the file. Actually it was working fine with using HttpRequest - Fiddler code. But the issue occurs once the view state changes then file was not able to download.
So everytime I'm changing the viewstate from Fiddler code and updating my file. I know I can use Selenium or Watin but I don't want to use them.

Link button code:

```
<a id="LinkButton1" class="verdana_normal" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1','')" style="color:RoyalBlue;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;position: static">Download File</a>
```

When I right click on link and copy the link address then it was "javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton3','')" only.

Is there any way I can download the file using webclient based on above href Link Button?

Any help or suggestions would be really helpful mates.

Comment: You could ask the website owner's permission to copy their content. I'm sure they would provide a direct download link for you if they are happy to be sharing their content in this way.

Comment: What does it have to do with C#?

Comment: @Lee The client will provide website only so we need to download the data and its public only. Even you can also download the file.

Comment: @user1990395: Whilst public content doesn't necessarily mean its free to copy/scrape, for the sake of pointing you in teh right direction... You either need to work out what the javascript does from looking at the website javascript sources, and see if its something that you can statically use (i.e. it might just call some JS that `window.location`'s you to the resource file), or you need something to act as an headless browser. Perl's mechanize library might work, failing that you could use an instance of PhantomJS

Comment: @Lee I know public website are not necessarily free to copy or download mate. They can only provide the data for world users to look at the market prices values. Thats up to us to download or look into their website. I will look into PhantomJS but never tried before mate